# Why does not Explicit Wait work for autosuggest boxes?

Tags: selenium, wait, autosuggest

I tried to use ExplicitWait for an autosuggest box but it did not work, so I am using simple `Thread.sleep(5000)`:

```
/***************************************************************************************/ 
                                // The below Thread.sleep(5000) works fine 
                        //                    Thread.sleep(5000); 

        // However the below Explicit Wait block does not recognize the element
                        WebDriverWait wait5000 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0);
                        wait5000.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='auto_suggest']/*[@class='title_item']")));
    /***************************************************************************************/    


                        WebElement firstItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='auto_suggest']/*[@class='title_item']"));
                        firstItem.click();
                          System.out.println("Done!");

                }

            }
```

I can use `Thread.sleep(5000)` but this is not efficient, because of time loss. Is there any way to introduce an explicit wait for the autosuggest box? How to click the autosuggest box more in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter in the constructor is the timeout in milliseconds.

Here `WebDriverWait wait5000 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0);` you are passing in `0`  - you are giving it a maximum of `0` milliseconds to find the element. You could try increasing the timeout, for example, let it search for the element for up to 5 whole seconds:

```
WebDriverWait wait5000 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank You for reply +1. I always use `...driver, 0)` because I do not want to give extra time. It works for ALL other WebElements in my code EXCEPT for this autosugges box